# How to Create access token from refresh token Google/YT API ? PHP

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-api, youtube-api

So I'm having issues trying to obtain the access token from a stored refresh token that I have already in a database.
I need to get the refresh token and use that to obtain an access token for use in a query like this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&id=" . $channel_url . "&access_token=" . $access_token . "
```

How can I get that access token from the refresh token I already have?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution myself :D All I had to do was define my refresh token and then re-inject it back into the YT API.

```
$refresh_token = 'X/XXXXXXX';
$client->refreshToken($refresh_token);
$_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
$access_token = json_decode($_SESSION['token'])->access_token;
```